# Fastest way to load large sparse matrix

Tags: python, csv, pandas, pickle, hdf

I've been playing around with trying to find the fastest way to access large datasets in Python.

In my real world case, I have a roughly 10,000 by 10,000 csv file which I'm loading into a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame, because I'm mainly taking dot products and summing over levels.

As loading this csv to pandas takes roughly a minute, I was looking for ways to improve this speed.

Upon investigation I came across this thread: [Why does saving/loading data in python take a lot more space/time than matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712482/why-does-saving-loading-data-in-python-take-a-lot-more-space-time-than-matlab)

What I got from this thread is that .mat files load faster because these are stored as hdf5. As such, I wanted to evaluate the performance of pickle, and hdf through h5py, pandas and scypio (to load the data from a .mat file).

The results for my real world case where the following:

```
pickle 65.48222637176514
h5py 65.20841789245605
pandas 65.45801973342896
mat 20.857333660125732
```

As can be seen, indeed loading the .mat file is over 3 times quicker then pickle and hdfs generated through Python. As such, the faster loading time of .mat files does not seem to be due to hdf as loading hdfs generated through python do not have this advantage.

Based on this, I wanted to post a question here asking what the quickest way is to load large datasets into python. For this, I made a toy example with some random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import h5py
import pandas as pd

#create random numpy ndarray
array_foo = np.random.rand(10000,10000)

#save array to pickle
pickle.dump(array_foo, open('array_foo.pkl', 'wb'))

#save array to hdf through h5py
h5py_hdf_store = h5py.File('array_foo.h5')
h5py_hdf_store['array_foo'] = array_foo
h5py_hdf_store.close()

#save pandas to hdf
df = pd.DataFrame(array_foo)
df.to_hdf('df_foo.h5', 'df_foo')

#save to csv for conversion to mat
df.to_csv('df_foo.csv')
```

After converting the csv to mat in MATLAB, I made the following test to evaluate loading time:

```
import pickle
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import scipy.io as sio
import time

#time pickle load
start_time = time.time()
pkl_array_foo = pickle.load(open('array_foo.pkl', 'rb'))
end_time = time.time()
delta_time = end_time - start_time
print('pickle', delta_time)

#time h5py load
start_time = time.time()
h5py_hdf_store = h5py.File('array_foo.h5')
h5py_array_foo = h5py_hdf_store['array_foo'][:,:]
end_time = time.time()
delta_time = end_time - start_time
print('h5py', delta_time)

#time pandas load
start_time = time.time()
df_array_foo = pd.read_hdf('df_foo.h5')
end_time = time.time()
delta_time = end_time - start_time
print('pandas', delta_time)

#time mat load
start_time = time.time()
dict_df_foo = sio.loadmat('mat_df_foo.mat')
mat_array_foo = dict_df_foo['mat_df_foo']
end_time = time.time()
delta_time = end_time - start_time
print('mat', delta_time)
```

The results were the following:

```
pickle 68.21923732757568
h5py 67.92283535003662
pandas 67.95403552055359
mat 67.09603023529053
```

Interestingly enough, it seems the .mat file lost its loading advantage here. Upon investigation, it turns out the real world data is highly sparse. To figure out how sparse, I replaced all the non zero values by ones, summed everything and divided by the size of the matrix. This yielded a density of about 0.28. With this number I replaced the random matrix in the toy example by a sparse one:

```
array_foo_sparse = sparse.random(10000,10000, density = 0.28)
array_foo = array_foo_sparse.todense()
```

Indeed, it seems like this did the trick:

```
pickle 69.06890630722046
h5py 68.73687291145325
pandas 69.12291169166565
mat 22.53125286102295
```

As such, I wanted to investigate whether saving as sparse would allow for faster loading time of pickle, pandas, and h5py. For this, I saved the sparse version directly to pickle, and saved a sparse version of the DataFrame:

```
pickle.dump(array_foo_sparse, open('array_foo.pkl', 'wb'))
df_sparse = df.to_sparse()
df_sparse.to_hdf('df_foo.h5', 'df_foo')
```

When trying to save through h5py I got an error:

```
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

After a bit of investigating it seems I should try to use chunked storage, but I felt I was moving away from my initial goal by investigating this further.

The results were as follows:

```
pickle 38.300209283828735
pandas 470.5342836380005
```

While pickle did seem to be sped up (but still not as fast as .mat), pandas took a huge hit, taking almost 8 minutes to load.

Lastly I tried to save to mat directly from python:

```
array_foo_sparse = sparse.random(10000,10000, density = 0.28)
array_foo = array_foo_sparse.todense()

sio.savemat('array_foo.mat', {'array_foo':array_foo})
```

Loading this yielded:

```
mat 73.23888158798218
```

And saving the sparse version:

```
array_foo_sparse = sparse.random(10000,10000, density = 0.28)
sio.savemat('array_foo.mat', {'array_foo':array_foo_sparse})
```

Yielded

```
mat 29.749581336975098
```

While faster, It's still almost 10 seconds slower than MATLAB's mat file.

As such, I'm left wondering where to go from here. Is there any way to achieve (or surpass) the performance of a MATLAB mat file? I would like to stay within the same environment (i.e. python, spyder), if possible.